# Wrong str.join implementation behavior?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, join, cpython

Consider the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = '123'

    def __len__(self):
        print('len')
        return 2

    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        print('get pos', pos)
        return self.a[pos]

a = A()
print(''.join(a))
```

My expected output:

```
> len
> get pos 0
> get pos 1
> 12
```

The real output:

```
> len
> get pos 0
> get pos 1
> get pos 2
> get pos 3
> 123
```

[Try it your self.](https://repl.it/repls/FreeObviousGraphs) I cannot believe what happens here.

As I understand the behavior correctly, *str.join()* calls *__len__* but ignores the value and calls *__getItem__* until the index out of range exception.

I must overlook something because the implementation of join seems different:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/stringlib/join.h

My current workaround is:

```
def __getitem__(self, pos):
    if pos >= len(self):
      raise IndexError()
return self.a[pos]
```

This is ridiculous.

I tested it under with Python 3.6 and 3.7 (CPython).

Comment: That's nothing to do with `str.join` specifically; `list(a)` behaves just the same, it iterates until `StopIteration` or `IndexError` is raised.

Comment: See: [What exactly are iterator, iterable, and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)

Comment: You should implement `__iter__`.

Comment: join checks if the object is a list or tuple (just to get the size right away). Not sure why it calls len...

Answer (score 1):

How `str.join` works (from analysing the source code)

First it checks if the object is an iterable & creates a sequence out of it if needed

```
seq = PySequence_Fast(iterable, "can only join an iterable");
```

If the object is a `list` or `tuple`, it just returns the object itself, no need to iterate.

If it's not, then it iterates to create a `list`. That's where the object is fully iterated upon.

From there, only the `list` copy is used. `iterable` has been iterated upon and is useless now if it wasn't `list` or `tuple`.

(I couldn't track down the call to `len`, would take a debugging session to find it in the `PySequence_Fast` call, but that seems useless. Your iterable has a `__len__` method, okay, but since it's not a `list` or `tuple`, the returned value isn't used)